# ONVIF GetSystemDateAndTime Request

Tags: onvif

Once I get a response back from the UDP Multicast Request to 239.255.255.250

I get back a ProbeMatch  with an XAddrs   `http://10.10.10.10:1234/onvif/device_service`

How do I now do the GetSystemDateAndTime  and GetDeviceInformation

Is this a TCP/UDP request to 10.10.10.10  port 1234 ?
Is this a HTTP request to 10.10.10.10     port 80   ?

Or What  Once I have the device's address   `http:10.10.10.10:1234/onvif/device_service`

Then what

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to send there just a HTTP request as SOAP works over HTTP. For example via CURL it would be like this:

```
curl 10.10.10.10:1234/onvif/device_service -d '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><GetSystemDateAndTime xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl"/></s:Body></s:Envelope>'
```

As a result you will get something like this with some headers:

```
<tds:GetSystemDateAndTimeResponse>
    <tds:SystemDateAndTime>
        <tt:DateTimeType>Manual</tt:DateTimeType>
        <tt:DaylightSavings>false</tt:DaylightSavings>
        <tt:TimeZone>
            <tt:TZ>MoroccoStandardTime0</tt:TZ>
        </tt:TimeZone>
        <tt:UTCDateTime>
            <tt:Time>
                <tt:Hour>10</tt:Hour>
                <tt:Minute>5</tt:Minute>
                <tt:Second>35</tt:Second>
            </tt:Time>
            <tt:Date>
                <tt:Year>2014</tt:Year>
                <tt:Month>3</tt:Month>
                <tt:Day>14</tt:Day>
            </tt:Date>
        </tt:UTCDateTime>
    </tds:SystemDateAndTime>
</tds:GetSystemDateAndTimeResponse>
```

And also dont forget that most of the actions requires authorization headers included in to the request.

**AUTHENTICATION**

In [ONVIF Application Programmer's Guide](https://www.onvif.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ONVIF_WG-APG-Application_Programmers_Guide-1.pdf) on page 35 is described how auth is done. For example it looks like this:

```
<s:Header>
    <Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <UsernameToken>
            <Username>admin</Username>
            <Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">MuMnyh3wTxGWOCc=</Password>
            <Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">8Qqve9KCkNhQAAAAAAA==</Nonce>
            <Created xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2014-03-04T14:03:05.130Z</Created>
        </UsernameToken>
    </Security>
</s:Header>
```

Comment: I know that GetSystemDateAndTimeResponse doesn't require authentication. you have a curl example of a command that does require username/password?

Comment: please tell me how to request onvif service, i have IP Camera and i want handle to PTZ functionality using OnVif service.

please help i need urgent, 

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

@Kirix solution didn't work for my particular camera. However, after a huge amount of code study and trail/error.. I determined that the Trendnet camera I have insists on the header being perfect. I figured out a curl variation:

```
curl http://192.168.xxx.xxx/onvif/device_service --data '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><GetSystemDateAndTime xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl"/></s:Body></s:Envelope>' --header 'Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/GetSystemDateAndTime";'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case `http://10.10.10.10:1234/onvif/device_service` is the address of the device management service. You need to send a `GetSystemDateAndTime` request according to the SOAP protocol.

How to send such requests depends on the system you are working on. You may use Visual Studio or gsoap (there's a [FAQ](https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapfaq.html) about ONVIF)