# Android communicate with camera usíng ONVIF

Tags: android, onvif

Android code to ONVIF Can someone help me. From an Android tablet I should communicate with a Samsung camera SNZ-5200. I need to stream and zoom in / out. camera use ONVIF protocol 
I have searched the ONVIF.com and other page. pleas help me with some Sample code.

Comment: check my older post http://stackoverflow.com/a/22401873/1735099

Comment: you need to generate the code from ONVIF wsdl files. check this tool https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/